# How do you cancel an external git diff?

Tags: git, vim, external, vimdiff

I've got vim setup as my external diff tool:

```
[diff]
        external = git_diff_wrapper

#!/bin/sh

vimdiff "$2" "$5"
```

Say I have 300 files that have been modified; via bash, I type "git diff".  It launches 300 vimdiffs sequentially, how do I abort it?

Comment: Note that the same solutions can be used with `git mergetool` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If stopping the process is not enough, killing the shell itself (in which you launched the `git diff`) might be more effective.

[image: http://trick.vanstaveren.us/wp/wp-uploads/2009/06/close-this-window.png]

---

See also [**Git Diff with Vimdiff**](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/git-diff-with-vimdiff/)

[image: VimDiff]

> Not being ready to go full speed into using `vimdiff` (I’m just new to it), I put the following in ‘`gitvimdiff`’.
>   The result is that I can use `vimdiff` to look at git-diff by running ‘`gitvimdiff`‘, but a normal invocation of ‘`git diff`’ behaves as I’m used to.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -n "${GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF}" ]; then
[ "${GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF}" = "${0}" ] ||
{ echo “GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF set to unexpected value” 1>&2; exit 1; }
exec vimdiff “$2″ “$5″
else
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=”${0}” exec git –no-pager diff “$@”
fi
```

---

But if you still want the modified `git diff`, a `git status` might help before launching it ;)

And you can setup a function to get the old `git diff` behavior if needed:

> I still have access to the default git diff behavior with the `--no-ext-diff` flag. Here’s a function I put in my bash configuration files:

```
function git_diff() {
  git diff --no-ext-diff -w "$@" | vim -R -
}
```

> - `--no-ext-diff`: to prevent using vimdiff
> - `-w`: to ignore whitespace
> - `-R`: to start vim in read-only mode
> - `-`: to make vim act as a pager

Answer (score 27):

Use :cquit to exit vim with an error code. Git will detect the error and stop opening new vimdiffs. You'll probably want to create a mapping for it in your .vimrc:

```
if &diff
  map Q :cquit<CR>
endif
```

Then just hit Q to early abort from a git diff run.

In order for this to work you must edit your gitconfig:

```
git config --global difftool.trustExitCode true
git config --global mergetool.trustExitCode true
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it directly addresses the question instead of providing a workaround. Wonderful idea for the `if &diff` mapping too. Thanks all around!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm not referring to the mapping but the :cquit command itself. Vim exits correctly but Git still carries on with the diffing process.

Comment: @kai https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool says you need to add --trust-exit-code to your git difftool command. My alias is now d = difftool --trust-exit-code after adding --trust-exit-code I can use :cq in vim to abort the diff.

Comment: @Jon I'm having the same problem as kai. trustExitCode and --trust-exit-code both don't work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: @kai I think I see now. difftool.trustExitCode seems to be present only in newer versions of git and is not available for e.g. git 1.9.1.

Comment: Thank you! :D I just needed out after a mistake I knew I needed to start all over because of.

Answer (score 2):

Just kill the parent process. Open up a terminal, use `pstree -p` to find the process ID (PID) of the `git` process, then `kill -9` it. On my system, it looks something like this:

```
$ pstree -p
...
        ├─gnome-terminal(20473)─┬─bash(10302)───git(10331)───pager(10332)
...
$ kill -9 10331
```

Not exactly elegant, but it works. On your system, `pager` will probably be something different, but it will have `git` as a parent process.