# (g)Vim with version control like Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, version-control, vim

I was an Eclipse user, now I have to use Vim in my machine.

I used to "compare" a file I edited with a CVS repository to do merges an commit the files, using a context menu and my mouse.

Is this possible in Vim? Opening a vimdiff for a file before commiting, and commit it from vim itself?

And how is that supposed to work?

I'm supposing I would be editing a file. Then, I want to see the modifications. I run vimdiff in gvim, and a new window (or buffer) is opened. I run the modifications, save what is applicable (using vimdiff commands), and commit running another command.

Is this all transparent in vim? Do I have to keep getting out of vim to my terminal, or can all be done inside it?

Do I need to use some plugins, or just really simple functions inside my vimrc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a couple plugins to integrate VCS to vim.
I personnally use [vcscommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90). It does at least the 2 things you're asking for: comparing from repository using vimdiff and commiting from within vim.

Answer (score 2):

I personally just switch between vim and the terminal.

Usually I'd have several console tabs open at the same time (if you're on windows, [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) can do that).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the VCS used, but you can linked that VCS with vimdiff (see [git, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786619/how-do-you-cancel-an-external-git-diff/2786634#2786634))

[image: VimDiff]

---

You could also try and integrate directly Vim into your Eclipse session with **[eclim](http://eclim.org/)**.
(should you still be using eclipse. If not, I leave the following for others)

It does support the [Eclipse local History](http://eclim.org/vim/common/history.html?highlight=diff).

[image: Eclim Use cases]