# git and vimdiff - close all files at once

Tags: git, vimdiff

When using vimdiff with git and lots of changed files, vimdiff will open each file sequentially. It opens up the next file once you have closed the current file.

But what if I just want to break out of the whole diff process and also do not want to have coming diffs open?

How can I stop all diffs when using vimdiff?

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15349459/6309

Comment: The `:cquit` method does not work, even directly. Vim continuous to open new files.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

OK, I found it.

in .gitconfig:

```
[difftool]
    # Be able to abort all diffs with `:cq` or `:cquit`
    trustExitCode = true
```

Then inside vim just enter `:cq` or `:cquit`. This will exit vim with error codes and git has been told to rely on the error codes with `trustExitCode`.

Comment: Nice catch (since my link did not help directly). +1

Comment: Your link helped to get me on track. :-) Thanks

Comment: In my case, the `:cq` command worked even without having the `[difftool]:trustExitCode` entry in `.gitconfig` :)

Answer (score 9):

> How can I stop all diffs when using vimdiff?

Probably no need to customize your `.gitconfig`. Use the vim commands instead:

`:qa` close all (without saving)
`:wqa` save all then quit

For both commands you can force the action by adding the `!` at the end:

`:qa!` force quit all (without saving any modifications)
`:wqa!` force quit all (force saving your modifications)

In vim check `:help :qa`

Comment: :qa does not stop vim from opening the files it hasn't opened yet

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked but it's what I was looking for!

Comment: to stop all diff `:windo diffoff` should do it.