# Can I abort git difftool when multiple files are being compared?

Tags: git, git-diff, vimdiff, git-difftool

I've made a huge mistake.

I've configured `git difftool` to use `vimdiff`, and then I've executed a command that compares the entire repository:

`git difftool tag1 tag2`

Now the difftool launches vim in diff mode for each file that has changed. When I close vim, it is launched again with the next pair of files. In general this is what I want, but can I abort this process somehow if there are too many files in the queue? I know I can close the terminal, but is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you cancel an external git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786619/how-do-you-cancel-an-external-git-diff) (Which has a better solution, IMO.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this: `git config --global difftool.prompt true`. That will prompt you for each pair of files it opens.

Comment: This works when done in a second terminal. Afterwards the difftool started asking and I was able to abort with `Ctrl-C`. Problem solved.